# Monorepo with Docker Compose, reloading dependencies

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have the following Docker Compose config:

```
foo-service:
    build:
      context: ./services/foo
      args:
        - NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN}
    volumes:
      - ./services/foo/:/app
      - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh -c "yarn dev"
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=8088
```

With the associated Dockerfile (in /services/foo)

```
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine

ARG NPM_TOKEN
ENV NPM_TOKEN="${NPM_TOKEN}"

COPY package.json .
COPY .npmrc .

RUN yarn

RUN rm -f .npmrc
```

And the `yarn dev` cmd:

`"dev": "npx nodemon lib/"`

(I'm using TS to compile from `/src` to `/lib` inside each Service dir.

I'm using Yarn Workspaces in conjunction with Lerna.

When I run `docker-compose up --build`, everything spins up, installs, and runs correctly.

TS correctly compiles the files on change, which then gets picked up by Nodemon and restarts the node process inside the Docker container (through docker-compose)

However. If I change a dependency of `foo-service`, the Docker container's node process is not only not restarted, but if I restart the whole container, the changes aren't picked up.

My (naive) guess:

When Docker Compose first runs, it picks up the package.json inside each Service, and installs the dependencies. However, when nodemon picks up a change, it restarts the Docker container node process, but I'm guessing doesn't re-install the dependencies. How can I get the docker container to pick up the changed, and symlinked (yarn workspaces/lerna), deps and restart the node process? (also, i'm obviously not publishing the packages to npm on each code change, so the package version the Docker container has inside package.json will point to the same version published on npm, not the local changed dep)

I definitely shouldn't have to, and don't want to, re-install all deps from npm on code change inside docker.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?